# Enums and State... Using a listener to time it - Java

Tags: java, enums

```
public class X {

    private long timeInactive = 0;
    private final long timeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private enum State {
        ACTIVE,INACTIVE
    };
    private State getState() {
        if(Math.random <= 0.1) {
            return State.ACTIVE;
        }
        return State.INACTIVE;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Let's pretend I had something like this. How would I input a listener that would time how long the state was inactive before once again becoming active, and do this every single time it went back to being inactive?

Edit: I need to know when getState() has changed value after being changed by random or external factors. For instance, in psvm, I might have something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        if(value of getState() has changed from inactive to active) {
            System.out.println(How long it was inactive prior);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something already? As it is now, the question looks too much like a fill-in-code-here request.

Comment: I really just need a push in the right direction... I haven't had much experience with enums.

Comment: I don't understand. You already have the enum part of the code written. What you're asking for is code for the listener part, but you should show some research effort for that..

Comment: I don't understand why you'd comment, and instead of trying to help, say "Look it up," when I've clearly already done that and not been able to find a clear answer. When people come to stackoverflow for help, whether they're looking at an old question, or are making their own, generally it's not too helpful to just say "Look it up," because that's the easier option, so if they're here, they've probably already done that.

Comment: I didn't say "look it up", I asked what you've already tried (research effort). That's something a good question should always include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**keep the time inside X without Listner**

```
public class X {

  private long timeInactive = 0; // total time of being inactive

  private long timeLastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
  private State currentState = State.INACTIVE;

  enum State {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE
  }

  public State getState() {
    changeState(); // It shouldn't be called here. I just need to simulate the state changing inside randomly
    return currentState;
  }

  private void changeState() {
    State oldState = currentState;
    if (Math.random() <= 0.1) {
      currentState = State.ACTIVE;
    } else {
      currentState = State.INACTIVE;
    }
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (oldState == State.INACTIVE && currentState == State.ACTIVE) {
      long elapse = now - timeLastChanged;
      timeInactive += elapse;
    }
    if (oldState != currentState) {
      timeLastChanged = now;
    }
  }

  public long getTotalTimeInActive() {
    return timeInactive;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    X x = new X();
    while (true) {
      x.getState();
      System.out.println(x.getTotalTimeInActive());
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

**With a listener:**

```
//Listner.java
interface Listener {
  void onStateChange(X2.State currentState);
}

//X2.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class X2 {
  private State currentState = State.INACTIVE;

  private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

  enum State {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE
  }

  public State getState() {
    changeState(); // It shouldn't be called here. I just need to simulate the state changing inside randomly
    return currentState;
  }

  private void changeState() {
    if (Math.random() <= 0.1) {
      currentState = State.ACTIVE;
    } else {
      currentState = State.INACTIVE;
    }
    for(Listener listener:listeners){
      listener.onStateChange(currentState);
    }
  }

  public void registerListener(Listener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    X2 x = new X2();
    TimeInactiveListener timeInactiveListener = new TimeInactiveListener();
    x.registerListener(timeInactiveListner);
    while (true) {
      x.getState();
      System.out.println(timeInactiveListner.getTimeInactive());
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}

class TimeInactiveListener implements  Listener {
  private long timeLastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
  private X2.State oldState = X2.State.INACTIVE;
  private long timeInactive = 0; // total time of being inactive
  @Override
  public void onStateChange(X2.State currentState) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (oldState == X2.State.INACTIVE && currentState == X2.State.ACTIVE) {
      long elapse = now - timeLastChanged;
      timeInactive += elapse;
    }
    if (oldState != currentState) {
      timeLastChanged = now;
    }
    oldState = currentState;
  }

  public long getTimeInactive() {
    return timeInactive;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to know when it changed states you would have to know what the last state was so you have something to compare it to. And then just check if the new state is different then the old state, and if so then record the time inactive.

```
private State state;
public void setState(State newstate){
    if (!newstate.equals(state)){
        if (state.equals(State.INACTIVE)){
            timeInactive = 0;
            timeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        else if (state.equals(State.ACTIVE)){
            timeInactive = System.currentTimeMillis()-timeStarted;
        }
    }
    state = newstate;
}
```

Also to do this you would need to change `timeStarted` to not be `final`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have nothing in your code that records the current state. You are defining a private `enum` but that is nothing more than declaring that a state can have two values: it doesn't actually record the state. To do that you'd need a field with state defined and the last time in changed state. Also note that by making it private it can only be used internally in the class. That might work in this situation (because `main` is part of the same class) but will generally not be what you want.

Ideally you should encapsulate that logic in a `State` class rather than have it in the class using the state.

```
public class State {
    public enum Value { ACTIVE, INACTIVE };

    private Value value = Value.INACTIVE;
    private long inactiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public Value getValue() {
        Value newValue = Math.random() < 0.1 ? Value.ACTIVE : Value.INACTIVE;
        if (newValue != value) {
            if (newValue == Value.ACTIVE)
                // notify listener with inactive period current - inactiveTime
            else
                inactiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            value = newValue;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```